# making changes to database with hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, crud

so im quite new to all spring and hibernate so i used a feature in myeclipse called generate CRUD application (it uses spring and hibernate for the heart of the application and JSF for presentation objects)that im intended to make changes so that i can work with .. my question is the following .. after i made the application that works fine by the way , i discovered that there are fields and probably even tables to be added to the database(an oracle 11g instance database)..so my questions are the following:

if i create the classes and update the existing .. will it be written directly in the database?
if not is there any way to do it because i dont think a direct update in the database will be a good idea .. 
thank you in advance ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to know whether the database schema can be created/updated automatically from your *@Entity* classes, and how to enable/disable such creation. Yes, it's possible by using some property. The name of the property would depend on your project kind. For example, in a default Spring Boot application, you can have

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: update
```

in *application.properties*. The value `update` above will have the schema automatically created on first run and then updated on subsequently. `validate` instead of `update` won't alter the schema, but just validate it.

This [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-possible-values-and-what-they-do#1689769) lists the possible values and their behaviour.